# Every time I logout & log back in a new cart is created, Django Cart App

Tags: python, django, cart

I'm new to Django! I'm trying to let unauthenticated users add products to cart. And when they login & refresh the cart is associated with user. But the problem is for authenticated users. When authenticated user logs out and logs back in, a new cart is created for him. This is my function, it checks if I need to make a new cart or get the existing one.

```
def new_or_get(self, request):
    cart_id = request.session.get("cart_id", None)
    qs = self.get_queryset().filter(id=cart_id)
    if qs.count() == 1:
       new_obj = False
       cart_obj = qs.first()
       if request.user.is_authenticated() and cart_obj.user is None:
           cart_obj.user = request.user
           cart_obj.save()
       else:
           cart_obj = Cart.objects.create(user=request.user)
           new_obj = True
           request.session['cart_id'] = cart_obj.id
       return cart_obj, new_obj
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add the user to the filter to ensure the user gets their cart because you link a user to a cart.

```
def new_or_get(self, request):
    cart_id = request.session.get("cart_id", None)
    filter_kwargs = {'id': card_id}
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        filter_kwargs.update({'user': request.user})

    qs = self.get_queryset().filter(**filter_kwargs)
    if qs.count() == 1:
       new_obj = False
       cart_obj = qs.first()
       if request.user.is_authenticated() and cart_obj.user is None:
           cart_obj.user = request.user
           cart_obj.save()
       else:
           cart_obj = Cart.objects.create(user=request.user)
           new_obj = True
           request.session['cart_id'] = cart_obj.id
       return cart_obj, new_obj
```

You could also have a look at a django helper method on models that might work something like this for you;

```
def new_or_get(self, request):
    cart_id = request.session.get("cart_id", None)
    filter_kwargs = {'id': card_id}
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        filter_kwargs.update({'user': request.user})

    cart_obj, created = Cart.objects.get_or_create(**filter_kwargs)

    if request.user.is_authenticated() and cart_obj.user is None:
       cart_obj.user = request.user
       cart_obj.save()

   request.session['cart_id'] = cart_obj.id
   return cart_obj, created
```

Check the docs here; https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create